# Robolectric: failed on start test cause of wifi start scan

Tags: android, android-wifi, robolectric

I've created a little test under Robolectric. Unfortunately, I must comment these lines for having success test :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private void setupApplication() {

....

//mNetworkEvents = new NetworkEvents(this, EventBus.getDefault())
//            .withPingUrl(BuildConfig.PING_SERVER_URL)
//            .withPingTimeout(BuildConfig.PING_TIMEOUT);

}
```

This class "NetworkEvents" allows to test internet connectivity. And in this class there is this call:

```
public static void startWifiScan(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.startScan();
}
```

And the problem is the start wifi scan...

This is error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.startScan(WifiManager.java:995)

How can I do run my test without comment these line in my application class ??

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce error and found same. I was thinking that you should first set `WifiManager` to start using it. However problem is deeper.

**Robolectric** has shadow class for `WifiManager` and it is returned to you but `startScan()` method is not shadowed and is trying to call real class from **Android**. If you take a look to sources there is `service` field, the implementation of WiFi details, in real class and that is null when running with **Robolectric**.

I created issue on the **Robolectric** github https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1969

Comment: Exactly Eugen! I found a work arround: I've created a buildvariant for the Unit Test, to set wifi using at false.